# Clojure: How do I turn clojure code into a string that is evaluatable? It mostly works but lists are translated to raw parens, which fails

Tags: string, list, clojure

I have a simple structure like this:

```
(def example {:bbb "bbb" :xxx [1 2 3] :yyy '(3 5 7)})
```

If I write this out to a file it contains

```
{:bbb "bbb" :xxx [1 2 3] :yyy (3 5 7)}
```

Which is mostly correct, but if I load-file on this, it fails because it tries to treat 3 as a function (the parens are no longer quoted, so tries to evaluate as a function).

What is the right way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to read back a Clojure datum previously written to a file as a literal, you need to use `read` or `read-string` rather than `load-file`:

```
(with-open [fd (java.io.PushbackReader.
                (io/reader (io/file "/path/to/file")))]
  (read fd))
```

You can call `read` multiple times to read successive forms (as long as you hold the `Reader` open, of course).

This involves no evaluation except when the `#=` reader macro occurs in the input stream, in which case the form immediately following it is evaluated at read time and replaced with the result in `read`'s output (e.g. `(read-string "#=(+ 1 2)")` returns `3`). To prohibit evaluation of `#=` prefixed forms bind `*read-eval*` to `false`.