# Clojure: generating files containing clojure breaks with persistent lists

Tags: function, file-io, clojure, eval

I asked a related question here: [Clojure: How do I turn clojure code into a string that is evaluatable? It mostly works but lists are translated to raw parens, which fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237364/clojure-how-do-i-turn-clojure-code-into-a-string-that-is-evaluatable-it-mostly)

The answer was great but I realized that is not exactly what I needed.  I simplified the example for stackoverflow, but I am not just writing out datum, I am trying to write out function definitions and other things which contain structures that contain lists.  So here is a simple example (co-opted from the last question).

I want to generate a file which contains the function:

```
(defn aaa []
  (fff :update {:bbb "bbb" :xxx [1 2 3] :yyy (3 5 7)}))
```

Everything after the :update is a structure I have access to when writing the file, so I call str on it and it emerges in that state.  This is fine, but the list, when I load-file on this generated function, tries to call 3 as a function (as it is the first element in the list).

So I want a file which contains my function definition that I can then call load-file and call the functions defined in it.  How can I write out this function with associated data so that I can load it back in without clojure thinking what used to be lists are now function calls?

Comment: So do I have to traverse the list of forms and replace all persistent lists with quoted persistent lists?  If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you just quote the map, or does it need to be evaluated too? `(defn aaa [] (fff :update '{:bbb "bbb" :xxx [1 2 3] :yyy (3 5 7)}))`? If that doesn't work you'll need to quote all `seq`s (if `(seq? x)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `quote` the structure prior to obtaining the string representation:

```
(list 'quote foo)
```

where `foo` is the structure.

Three additional remarks:

1. traversing the code to quote all lists / seqs would not do at all, since the top-level `(defn ...)` form would also get quoted;
2. lists are not the only potentially problematic type -- symbols are another one (`+` vs. `#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@451ef443>`);
3. rather than using `(str foo)` (even with `foo` already quoted), you'll probably want to print out the quoted `foo` -- or rather the entire code block with the quoted `foo` inside -- using `pr` / `prn`.

The last point warrants a short discussion. `pr` explicitly promises to produce a readable representation if `*print-readably*` is `true`, whereas `str` only produces such a representation for Clojure's compound data structures "by accident" (of the implementation) *and still only if `*print-readably*` is `true`*:

```
(str ["asdf"])
; => "[\"asdf\"]"

(binding [*print-readably* false]
  (str ["asdf"]))
; => "[asdf]"
```

The above behaviour is due to `clojure.lang.RT/printString`'s (that's the method Clojure's data structures ultimately delegate their `toString` needs to) use of `clojure.lang.RT/print`, which in turn chooses output format depending on the value of `*print-readably*`.

Even with `*print-readably*` bound to `true`, `str` may produce output inappropriate for `clojure.lang.Reader`'s consumption: e.g. `(str "asdf")` is just `"asdf"`, while the readable representation is `"\"asdf\""`. Use `(with-out-str (pr foo))` to obtain a string object containing the representation of `foo`, guaranteed readable if `*print-readably*` is `true`.

Comment: Marczyk, you are a lifesaver.  Seriously.  Also, I see now this all warrants some research into the subtleties of read/eval/print, as this is kind of at the heart of the matter!  Thanks for the glimpse into this wooly world.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a call to `quote` to read it without evaluating it.

Comment: The deal is I *want* to eval it, everything works fine but lists!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
(defn aaa []
  (fff :update {:bbb "bbb" :xxx [1 2 3] :yyy (list 3 5 7)}))
```